# Wearing pieces from two different sets of tefillin

Tags: halacha, mitzvah, tefilin

Tefillin are usually thought of as coming in sets, one for the hand (shel yad) and one for the head (shel rosh). But is there any reason two sets can't be mixed and matched? May one wear tefillin where the shel yad and the shel rosh come from different sets, my shel rosh and some other guy's shel yad? Does it make a difference if this is a temporary measure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is permitted.

A problem of כסדרן may appear - Rm"a addresses this ([OC 32:1](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9C%D7%91_%D7%90)) and says it should be taken care of לכתחילה, but if not it's not פסול.

Regarding Rashi & Rabenu Tam - it would be contradicting to wear Yad of one and Rosh of another. However, Rabbi Ya'akov Medan says [it is לכתחילה](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9F#.D7.A1.D7.93.D7.A8_.D7.94.D7.A4.D7.A8.D7.A9.D7.99.D7.95.D7.AA) to wear rashi for Yad and Rabenu Tam for Rosh.

Comment: A) It would not be contradicting to wear one of each RT and Rashi. The two tefillin aren't m'akeiv each other. B) I'm fairly certain R Medan said that as a theoretical suggestion, not that he or anyone follows that practically. It's actually a pretty interesting suggestion in terms of understanding how the machloket came about.

Comment: @DoubleAA, A) It's either one way or the other. If you would ask Rabenu Tam - someone wearing rashi isn't yotze. B) I understood that's his understanding of the gemara.

Comment: I agree with the above answers, but I wish to add a detail. In the case where the parchment in the Yad or the Rosh of a pair of tefilin is pasul (invalid) because there is a problem with the writing, you can still use the one that is kosher and make one of the two brachot (as appropriate) on that one.. this differs from what was told to me in a personal situation where the sofer said that the tefilin were pasul, could not be corrected or used...